# HCL Notes client: Events not working in dialogBox form

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Somehow, none of the standard Events in a Notes form are operational when used in a dialogBox call (onChange, onClose). One could argue that this a feature, but for me it definitely isn't.

```
If workspace.DialogBox( "FilterDB", True, True, False, False,  False, False, title, dlgdoc, 
    True, False, True ) Then
```

The form has a few fields and some JavaScript for the Notes client, in order to allow type-ahead in a text field. There's also a rich-text field in the form, it's only used as a transport mechanism for texts > 64Kb. And there's are a few buttons on the form that perform some transformations on the data. Two buttons are hidden, they are clicked by the JavaScript code.

It's a new form, work in progress, and in earlier incarnations of the form the Events used to work, I'm pretty sure of that. I'll try to remove some elements from the form, maybe those events will come back to life again.

Has anyone else observed this (on Notes V12), or does anyone know why many (if not all) form Events aren't triggered? Or what I can do to reactivate them?

Comment: I created a Form and filled all Form- Events and "onFocus" and "onChange" of two fields, one with JavaScript and one with LotusScript... everything worked, either in a document that I opened "normally" as well as one I opened as DialogBox with your code above... I tested with Notes 11.0.1FP4. What version do you use?

Comment: N12, Q updated, thanks!

Comment: Cross checked my test- form with Notes 12: Works as well... seems there is something wrong in your code / form...

Comment: Nope... see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered why the events aren't executed: I used an agent to test the DialogBox. Apparently, events aren't triggered when the dialog box isn't started from an active form.

I created a dummy form with a button that starts the dialog box, and all events work. Now, luckily, the dialog box will be called from within a form in most cases, so problem solved. Thanks!

PS I don't think it's really logical for a DialogBox to behave like this. Why shouldn't events be fired in a solitary dialog box??

Comment: The example I did was a Form in a database and then an Agent that Used `Set dlgdoc = New NotesDocument( db ), Call workspace.DialogBox( "FilterDB", True, True, False, False,  False, False, title, dlgdoc, 
    True, False, True )`, called it... worked perfectly... something else must be wrong in your example.

Comment: Oh really?? All I did is put a button in a new dummy form to call the DialogBox function and everything works as it should. No other changes. How odd. Maybe some references to NotesUIWorkspace or the current document are invalid? You create an empty NotesDocument for dlgdoc as well?

Comment: Here is, what I did: 1) Create form in my "dummy test database" and put Print or Msgbox (LotusScript) and alert (JavaScript) in all events, 2) Create an agent with above code (as you see: I create a "new" dlgdoc), 3) Run Agent from workspace with only the Tile selected (database not open). Agent was set to "Target = None". Interestingly: When running the agent from designer (right click - run) I can really reproduce your issue: No Field events, but form events trigger. Is there an embedded view in this form? I found out once, that this can stop the events of the form the be triggered...

Comment: I did indeed start the Agent from the Designer (and why not, it's there;-)), so that explains why some events aren't triggered. But in my case even the PostOpen wasn't fired (I also had Target=None). As for the embedded view: no such thing, and in the end, the form was completely empty and still no events. Thank you for testing this!! I'm moving on, my client gets impatient...